# Error de integración Jquery-formset y django-autocomplete-light

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, autocompletar

Tengo un problema y es que  estoy usando 2 bibliotecas: **django-**autocomplete-light** y **django-dynamic-formset**. Los 2 son muy buenos para hacer su trabajo. El primero lo uso para el autocompletado en un campo foreing key y el segundo para hacer que los formsets de django sean dinámicos o sea poder agregar o quitar formsets. pero cuando quieres unir a estos 2 ocurre un problema.

Aquí funciona correctamente porque es solo 1
[image: Aquí funciona correctamente]

Pero al momento de agregar otro:
[image: Deja de funcionar]

Deja de funcionar y estoy tratando de solucionar ese problema ya que al parecer es la forma en como duplica los formsets la librería **django-dynamic-formset**

Mi Template:

```
  {% extends 'base/base.html' %}
  {% load static %}
  {% block titulo%} Registrar venta {%endblock%}
  {% block contenido %}
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
    <label class="font-weight-bold" for="{{form.cliente.name}}">
    {{form.cliente.label}}</label>
     {{form.cliente}}
   </div>
<h4 class="text-left">Detalle de venta: </h4>
<div class="table-responsive-sm">
    <table class="table" id="tablaDetalle">
        {{ detalleformset.management_form }}
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <th>Producto</th>
            <th width="100px">Cantidad</th>
            <th width="115px">Prec.Unit.</th>
            <th width="115px">Subtotal</th>
            <th>Acción</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for form in detalleformset.forms %}
            <tr class="formset_row">
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    <td>
                        {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                        {% if forloop.first %}
                            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                {{ hidden }}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                        {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                        {{ field }}
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-md-end">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="font-weight-bold" for="{{form.total.name}}">{{form.total.label}}</label>
    {{form.total}}
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="font-weight-bold" for="{{form.descripcion.name}}">{{form.descripcion.label}}</label>
    {{form.descripcion}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit"><span><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
      </span>Registrar venta</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
   {% endblock %}
   {% block javascript %}
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
   {{ detalleformset.media }}
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.formset_row').formset({
     addText: 'Agregar Producto',
     deleteText: 'remover',
     prefix: 'detalleventa'
    });
   </script>   
   {% endblock %}
```

Hay alguna solución a esto? estuve buscando pero hay escasa información.

**UPDATE** forms.py:

```
from dal import autocomplete
from django import forms
from apps.venta.models import Venta,DetalleVenta
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory

class VentaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Venta
        fields = [
            'cliente',
            'descripcion',
            'total',
        ]
        labels = {
            'cliente':'Cliente:',
            'descripcion':'Descripción de pedido:',
            'total':'Total S/.',
        }
        widgets ={
            'cliente':forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Ejm:Nicolas','class':'form-control','required':True}),
            'descripcion': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':'3','placeholder':'Ejm: 1 con ensalada y la otra solo mostaza'
                ,'class': 'form-control'}),
            'total': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control-plaintext total','placeholder': '0.00','required':True, 'readonly':True}),
        }

class DetalleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DetalleVenta
        fields = [
            'producto',
            'cantidad',
            'preciounit',
            'subtotal',
        ]
        labels = {
            'producto':'Producto',
            'cantidad':'Cantidad',
            'preciounit':'Prec.Unit.',
            'subtotal':'Subtotal',
        }
        widgets = {
            'producto': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='producto-autocomplete'),
            'cantidad':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control cantidad', 'required': True}),
            'preciounit':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control-plaintext', 'placeholder':'0.00','readonly':True}),
            'subtotal':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control-plaintext subtotal', 'placeholder':'0.00','readonly':True}),
        }
DetalleFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Venta, DetalleVenta,
                                       form=DetalleForm, extra=1)
```

Comment: ¿Cómo cargas las librerías en tu proyecto y cómo las importas a tu página? Además, ¿qué campos son los que haces el autocompletado? No termina de quedar claro dentro del código.

Comment: ¿podrías añadir el código del formulario que estás usando? Lo más seguro que el error esté ahí

Comment: Mi forms.py? no creo ya que si no utilizo **django-autocomplete-light** normal me genera los campos dinamicamente pero al utilizarla y querer agregar otro formulario pasa eso... pero de igual manera actualizo la pregunta :D muchas gracias

Comment: @PieroPajares preguntaba por cómo se importaban y llamaban porque mirando en internet se menciona que puede haber fallos de integración y falla si se llama a formset después de autocomplete. El orden de carga importa, y tienes que llamar a formset antes de form.media (al contrario de como parece lo tienes ahora). Prueba a mover el form.media a después del formset y comprueba si así funciona.

Comment: Si yo tambien leí algo así pero cuando importo el form.media luego del formset, el javascript deja de funcionar por alguna razón :/

Comment: hey @PieroPajares ¿lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: @fredyfx Si el año pasado luego de 1 semana lo solucione. Deseas que publique la solución? además deje de usar jquery ahora vue es la voz :D!

Comment: Sí por favor, luego la marcas como aceptada. De esta manera ayudas a la salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas)

Comment: No hay problema, de un toque la subo

Comment: @PieroPajares por curiosidad bro, ¿cuánto demora "un toque"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El año pasado lo llegue a resolver y disculpen si no publiqué la respuesta ya que por el trabajo no he tenido mucho tiempo

La librería **django-autocomplete-light** funciona bien pero cuando quieres crear o agregar formularios dinámicos que fue en mi caso, falla.

Que es lo que pasa? al agregar un nuevo formulario con la librería **django-dynamic-formset** esta efectivamente agregaba un nuevo campo pero **django-autocomplete-light** no vuelve a cargar sus css.

Para suerte esta librería **django-autocomple-light** usa **select2** y bueno simplemente es llamar cada vez que damos click en uno nuevo cargar el css de este mismo:

Primero cremos la función que llama al css de select2

```
function InicializaAutocomplete(){
  $('.autocomplete').select2({placeholder: 'Seleccione un producto'});
}
```

y luego cuando damos click en agregar uno nuevo llamamos a esta función en el **added** y al último le agregué tambien que se ejecute cuando se cargue la página para ponerle el mismo placeholder pero es opcional:

```
$('.formset_row').formset({
    addText: 'Agregar Producto',
    deleteText: 'remover',
    prefix: 'detalleventa',
    added:InicializaAutocomplete
 });
 //OPCIONAL
 InicializaAutocomplete();
```

y bueno esa es la solución :D de todas maneras les recomiendo ya dejar de usar jquery y pasarse a **vuejs**, **reactjs** o **angularjs** y **django** solo como backend que para esto tenemos a [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org) :D! un abrazo!!